# How to avoid placing watermark on small images

Tags: php, .htaccess, watermark

I will get to the point. I have installed Watermark using htaccess. Everything is working but I have no idea on how to make script NOT to place watermark on images smaller than 200x200. Also watermark is displaying a grayish line on the bottom where watermark.png sopose to be. How do I remove that line?

I oppologise for showing no effort. i did research for 4 hours and modify it so bad that my pictures was ruined. I found the line to add to php to not place watermark on small images, but do not know where to place it.

Here is the .php that places the watermark on image. Please help Is it is way to complicated for me.

```
<?php
$basedir="/uploads/";
$watermarkimage="tbwm.png";

$file=basename($_GET['i' ]);

$image = $basedir."/".$file;
$watermark = $basedir."/".$watermarkimage;

$im = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);

$ext = substr($image, -3);

if (strtolower($ext) == "gif") {
if (!$im2 = imagecreatefromgif($image)) {
echo "Error opening $image!"; exit;
}
} else if(strtolower($ext) == "jpg") {
if (!$im2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($image)) {
echo "Error opening $image!"; exit;
}
} else if(strtolower($ext) == "png") {
if (!$im2 = imagecreatefrompng($image)) {
echo "Error opening $image!"; exit;
}
} else {
die;
}
imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0  , (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)) , imagesx($im2)  , imagesy($im2) , imagecolorallocatealpha($im2, 0, 0, 0, 100) );
imagecopy($im2, $im, (imagesx($im2)-(imagesx($im))), (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)), 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

$last_modified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T' , filemtime ($image));

header("Last-Modified: $last_modified");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im2,NULL,95);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($im2);

?>
```

Comment: How about contacting the script support? It's not a site where we do your job for free.

Comment: so... your question is about .htaccess, yet, your htaccess code is not shown to us. if the url supposedly supported by htaccess doesn't work, why would you be able to access it from php, or anywhere else?

Comment: I did, but there was no reply to me. I did research and found this line from other script that didnt work for me, I sopose this line is responsible for not placing watermark // The watermark is imposed only on the image to 250 pixels vertically and horizontally.
 if( ($info_o[0] > 250) && ($info_o[1] > 250) )   and php for dummies said that this name is responsible for gray line "imagefilledrectangle" , but there was no examples on how to change it.

Comment: The question is about php, but I'm using htaccess to get to that php, I was just giving the idea of what I was doing.

Comment: htaccess (which means apache) has no way of getting an image's size. This is something you do in php, and has absolutely nothing to do with htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fast way:
just put the `imagecopy` function call into the `if(imagesx(im2) > 250 && imagesy(im2) > 250)`

```
if (imagesx($im2) > 250 && imagesy($im2) > 250) {
    imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0  , (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)) , imagesx($im2)  , imagesy($im2) , imagecolorallocatealpha($im2, 0, 0, 0, 100));
    imagecopy($im2, $im, (imagesx($im2)-(imagesx($im))), (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)), 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
}
```

long way:
put everything created for the watermark im inside the `if`

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work. I have made this change, cleared history and cache. Uploaded photo and nothing is showing. Watermark did not show on small or in big images. Besides that gray line.

Comment: Ups... check again... the imagesx($im2) inside the IF where missing the $ for the variable im2

Comment: I figured it out. I placed this if(imagesx($im2) > 250 && imagesy($im2) > 250) with $ sign, and it worked.  But this Gray line shows on every picture. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks man! How about Gray line, it is on every picture, even on the small pictures. Ok I will put screen. Hold on.

Comment: I did it. i removed imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0  , (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)) , imagesx($im2)  , imagesy($im2) , imagecolorallocatealpha($im2, 0, 0, 0, 100) ); And it's good no :) Thank you so much sir!

Comment: That's what I was about to say... the problem is imagefilledrectangle